# Having issues with I2S with DMA using bare metal

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, i2s

I am trying to setup the I2S Peripheral to interact with the [Pmod I2S module](https://store.digilentinc.com/pmod-i2s2-stereo-audio-input-and-output/). The FW and SCLK are not generating, however I can see the MCLK on the oscilloscope.

Using the [ST32H753ZI](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00314099-stm32h742-stm32h743753-and-stm32h750-value-line-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf)

What I have done so far are the following:

- Setup the SPI1/I2S Clock
- Enable the GPIOA, GPIOC, DMA1, and SPI1 Clocks
- Let SP1 use the PLL2 Clock
- Setup GIPO A and C for alternative functions for A5F (PA4, PA5, PA6,
  PA7, PC4)
- Setup DMAMUX1
- Setup DMA1 Stream0/1 for Tx and Rx
- Setup SPI

I tried using the HAL driver and that got the FW and SCLK showing on the oscilloscope. Comparing the bare metal code and the HAL code I cant find the difference between them as the registers are all setup the same.

Any ideas what's causing the FW and SCLK not to show?

Code:

```
void init_I2S(){

    //Setting Clock for 98.304MHz
    //N = 122
    //P = 8
    //M = 10
    //FRACT = 7209

    // RCC_PLL2DIVR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2;
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR &= ~RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR |= RCC_PLL2DIVR_P2_DIV8;
    RCC -> PLL2DIVR |= RCC_PLL2DIVR_N2_MULT122;

    // RCC_PLLCKSELR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR &= ~RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLLCKSELR |= RCC_PLLCKSELR_DIVM2_DIV10;

    // RCC_PLL2FRACR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLL2FRACR &= ~RCC_PLL2FRACR_FRACN2;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLL2FRACR |= RCC_PLL2FRACR_FRACN_7209;

    // RCC_PLLCFGR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP2EN;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2VCOSEL;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR &= ~RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2FRACEN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_DIVP2EN;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2RGE_4_8;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2VCOSEL_192_836;
    RCC -> PLLCFGR |= RCC_PLLCFGR_PLL2FRACEN;

    // RCC_CR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> CR &= ~RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> CR |= RCC_CR_PLL2ON;
    // WAITING:
    while (((RCC -> CR) & (RCC_CR_PLL2RDY)) == 0){};

    // ENALBING CLOCKS

    // RCC_AHB4ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> AHB4ENR &= ~ RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC -> AHB4ENR &= ~ RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOCEN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOAEN;
    RCC -> AHB4ENR |= RCC_AHB4ENR_GPIOCEN;

    // RCC_APB2ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> APB2ENR &= ~RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;

    // CHANGING CLOCKS OF PERIPHERALS
    // RCC_D2CCIP1R
    // MASKING;
    RCC -> D2CCIP1R &= ~RCC_D2CCIP1R_SPI123SEL;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> D2CCIP1R |=  RCC_D2CCIP1R_SPI123SEL_PLL2_P_CK;

    // CHANGING GPIO PINS TO ALETERNATIVE
    // GPIOx_MODER
    // MASKING
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE4;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE5;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE6;
    GPIOA -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE7;
    GPIOC -> MODER &= ~GPIO_MODER_MODE4;
    // WRITING:
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE4_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE5_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE6_ALT;
    GPIOA -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE7_ALT;
    GPIOC -> MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODE4_ALT;

    //SETTING ALT FUNCTIONS TO PINS
    // GPIOx_AFRL
    // MASKING:
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7;
    GPIOC -> AFR[0] &= ~GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4;
    // WRITING;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_AF5;
    GPIOA -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_AF5;
    GPIOC -> AFR[0] |= GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL4_AF5;

    // ENABLING DMA1
    // RCC_AHB1ENR
    // MASKING:
    RCC -> AHB1ENR &= ~RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;
    // WRITING:
    RCC -> AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_DMA1EN;

    // SETTING UP DMA FOR I2S
    // DMAMUX1_Channel0_CCR
    // DMAMUX1_Channel1_CCR
    // NOTE: Using DMAMUX1 -> DMA1_Channel 0 & 1
    // 0x25 = Rx | 0x26 = Tx
    // MASKING:
    DMAMUX1_Channel0 -> CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID;
    DMAMUX1_Channel1 -> CCR &= ~DMAMUX_CxCR_DMAREQ_ID;
    // WRITING:
    DMAMUX1_Channel0 -> CCR |= 0x25; //Rx
    DMAMUX1_Channel1 -> CCR |= 0x26; //Tx

    // DMA1_Stream0_CR
    // DMA1_Stream1_CR
    // MASKING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PL;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PSIZE;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_DIR;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR &= ~DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL;
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Very_High;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_P_TO_M;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_TCIE;
    DMA1_Stream0 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_HTIE;

    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CT_MEM0;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PL_Very_High;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PSIZE_32BIT;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_MINC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_CIRC;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_DIR_M_TO_P;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> CR |= DMA_SxCR_PFCTRL_DMAFLOW;

    // DMA_SxNDTR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> NDTR = 0x08;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> NDTR = 0x08;

    // DMA_SxPAR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> PAR = (uint32_t)&SPI1->TXDR;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> PAR = (uint32_t)&SPI1->RXDR;

    // DMA_SxM0AR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 -> M0AR = (uint32_t)RxBuff;
    DMA1_Stream1 -> M0AR = (uint32_t)TxBuff;

    // DMA_SxCR
    // WRITING:
    DMA1_Stream0 ->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;
    DMA1_Stream1 ->CR |= DMA_SxCR_EN;

    // Setting up the SPI/I2S Peripheral
    // MASKING:
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_MCKOE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_ODD;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SDIV;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_DATFMT;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_WSINV;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_DATLEN;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_CHLEN;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_CKPOL;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SSTD;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SCFG;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR &= ~SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SMOD;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1    &= ~SPI_CFG1_FTHLV;
    // WRITING:
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_MCKOE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_ODD_MULT2;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SDIV_2;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_DATFMT_RAlign;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_WSINV_I2S;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_DATALEN_24BIT;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_CKPOL_FALL_RISE;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SSTD_I2STAND;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SCFG_MASTER_TRANSMIT;
    SPI1 -> I2SCFGR |= SPI_I2SCFGR_I2SMOD_I2S_PCM_MODE;
    SPI1 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_RXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_TXDMAEN;
    SPI1 -> CFG1 |= SPI_CFG1_FTHLV_2_Data;
    SPI1 -> SR = 0x00;
    SPI1 ->  CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
    SPI1 ->  CR1 |= SPI_CR1_CSTART;

















}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the DMA Rx and Tx Peripheral and Memory were switched around.

Comment: Can you mark it as answered?

Comment: @winny it wont let me till tomorrow.